# FFMPEG - Malformed .aac tracks sound PERFECT in Movie Studio, but return "Input buffer exhausted before END element found" error when attempting mux

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am a novice ffmpeg user trying to mux h.264 video with a secondary .wav commentary track, without re-encoding anything on the video side. The video's audio is in .aac.

I use Bandicam to record footage; there is a setting to record a separate .wav file (the commentary) simultaneously.

When I initially tried to figure this out, I opened a thread (link at the bottom) and was quite thrilled with the helpfulness of the user that responded. The answer seemed to satisfy my question completely. Now, however, I have a new problem and I'd thus like to ask about it openly.

Some recordings are returning the error I mentioned in the header when I try to mux the commentary back onto the video. "Input buffer exhausted before END element found" is the error. The files finish muxing, but if the error happens enough times, noticeable video/audio desync occurs in the video. I updated my FFMPEG executables to the latest builds, and the previous helpful soul pointed out I might have "malformed audio streams."

But again, (1) it's not all of them, only some, and (2) both audio streams (original recording audio and commentary) sound flawless when I load the .mp4 into Movie Studio. So I'm tempted to say ffmpeg/avanti is the culprit.

Regardless, I have no idea what the solution could be. Please help if you have any idea.

[Here's the original thread, for your reference.](http://Input%20buffer%20exhausted%20before%20END%20element%20found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AAC audio is composed of frames. Each frame contains various types of elements. The last element in each frame is the END element. The error message you receive indicates that FFmpeg has surveyed the frame but hasn't found the END element. So, it skips that frame during remux, and that eventually breaks sync if too many of those occur. So here are a few attempts to work around that.

**#1** Preserve original timestamps

```
ffmpeg -copyts -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac video-new.mp4
```

**#2** Ignore stream errors and preserve original timestamps

```
ffmpeg -copyts -err_detect ignore_err -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac video-new.mp4
```

**#3** Encode video's audio but preserve gaps due to corrupted frames

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]aresample=async=1:min_comp=0.02[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 aac -c:a:1 aac video-new.mp4
```

Comment: You're a one-man army. I'll fiddle and get back to you on this thread. Thank you again.

Comment: I have another try encoding right now. Here's the command line I'm using per our last talk, plus the suggested changes from #2. See anything that needs fixing?

-copyts -err_detect ignore_err -filter_complex "[0:a][1]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a:0 aac -c:a:1 aac

Comment: Forgot you were using that command. Just used the one in my answer. Use `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]aresample=async=1:min_comp=0.02[sync];[sync][1]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a aac video-new.mp4`

Comment: ...that...appears to have fixed it. Bravo!! So, should I save this code for troublemaker files, or can I use it across the board and it'll simply apply the fix when there are corrupted frames?

Comment: You can use it across the board.

Comment: Just tested the fix on a video I made earlier for pure troubleshooting, one that had a particularly large number of errors... and I'm noticing now that the .mp4 non-commentary audio is desynced with the video. Any tweaks to suggest?

Comment: How much desync? And how did you create the file?

Comment: I noticed that a particular title's load/transition screens seemed to line up with the timestamps at which the errors were occurring in muxing, so I recorded a brief video in that title, going back and forth through the loading screen. And the desync is ~1 second.

Comment: Add `-vsync 0` and try. Also, record your videos using constant frame rate mode. See https://www.bandicam.com/support/tips/vfr-cfr/

Comment: Same desync. Minimal/no change. Had bad experience with CFR in the past, but happy to try again now that I am incorporating FFMpeg.

Comment: Suggest testing it with other regular recordings. The test video may be an outlier.

Comment: Mulvya, just an update for your information. You're far more skilled in this area than me, but I hope this may help the next time someone with a dilemma similar to this comes along. Ironically, my fix was staring me in the face the whole time. After I would mux all of my VFR recordings, only having issues in certain cases as we've discussed, I would handbrake them to get them ready for upload. Thing is, Handbrake actually converts files to CFR flawlessly. If I handbrake, then mux commentary, Avanti is handling a CFR file from the outset; no errors, no audio desync. It's perfect.

Comment: So far, we've been copying the video stream. Handbrake doesn't do that and recompresses the video. If you're ready to do that, you can do it from within ffmpeg itself. Replace `-c:v copy` with `-c:v libx264 -crf N` where N=20 or whatever. But why recompress video? Not needed.

Comment: When switching to CFR recording to avoid the Avanti error we were working with, file size per recording jumped dramatically. Not the most convenient thing in the world, and the files take much longer to load into any program I need to edit them in... using Handbrake to compress the video prior to the mux has no noticeable effect on quality, dramatically shrinks the video size, and makes the file CFR, thus eliminating the error. It may be convoluted, but for now it appears to be helping in more ways than one. Could be wrong, but it's progress.

Comment: I meant that you can use ffmpeg to compress the video, skipping Handbrake. They both use the same library to compress to H.264 -> x264.

Comment: Oh, I'm with you. The issue is that the fix we arrived at in the above exchange last week didn't fully address the audio sync issue, despite all our (your?) efforts. While this new "fix" is pretty bootleg, so far it appears to be working, so I wanted to send the feedback and close the loop. But, I'll give the new command a shot when I get the chance... see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have used above command for Encode video's audio but preserve gaps due to corrupted frames but still i see error on ffmpeg command line . this has significantly reduce the audio jerks which was coming on the hls player.

Kindly advice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241329)